# Как подключать native библиотеки в jar файл при сборке?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

При сборке jar файла когда сторонние  библеотеки  добавляешь надо .dll и .so   в манифесте указывать? И в манифесте в строке Class-Path: можно указать просто папку с библиотеками или надо каждый jar файл прописывать? И если кому не сложно можно сразу скинуть пример манифеста скинуть с пояснениями.
Заранее спасибо) всем + к карме

UPD:надо ли папку с ресурсами (./res) указывать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну на самом деле в Intelij idea все легко делается:
        1. жмем ctrl+alt+shift+s
        2. Artefacts
        3. жмем на плюсик, jar, from modules...
        4. указываем главный класс и путь где появится jar
        5. Во вкладки Build жмем на Build Artefacts, ниже должно появиться маленькое окошко, там и выбираем созданный артефакт и жмем build.
        6. Если хотим подключить библиотеку или папку с ресурсами и тд, закидываем .dll или .so файлы в папку с jar файлом (это для библиотек), и  папку res тоже закидываем к jar (это для ресуросв)
        7. для запуска на linux создаем файлик с .sh расширением (например start.sh)
и пишем туда:  `#!usr/bash java -Djava.library.path="./path_to_libs/" -jar name_of_jar_file.jar`
для запуска на win создаем start.bat
и записываем  `java -Djava.library.path="./path_to_libs/" -jar name_of_jar_file.jar`  8.Запускаем!

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо пользоваться каким нибудь фреймворком для автоматизации сборки проектов. Например, как [maven](/questions/tagged/maven) или [gradle](/questions/tagged/gradle).

Они очень облегчают задачу сборки проектов. Так как у них есть репозиторий (хранилище) библиотек, и Вам надо будет просто указать их в файле сборки проекта, в **pom.xml** в случае [maven](/questions/tagged/maven) или **build.gradle** в случае [gradle](/questions/tagged/gradle).

Но если вы все-таки хотите собрать проект или jar файл без них, то в качестве примера я посоветовал бы Вам заглянуть в исходниках библиотеки [SQLite](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc). Как раз они в папке **resources** добавляют native библиотеки.
Там можно даже в zip архиве скачать если не хотите заморачиваться git'ом.

Comment: оказывается это гипер сложно для того овоща как я, мб есть другой способ))

Comment: На сегодняшний день проекты на java трудно представить без них. Если вы в дальнейшем хотите создавать проекты на java, то Вам обязательно надо будет их изучать. Для начала основ будет достаточно чтобы вы могли создать и собрать какие-то проекты.

Comment: @naughtyBit А вообще вы как импортируете .dll или .so библиотеки на java классы сейчас?

Comment: я на линуксе, так что через .dll, но я делаю в команде (синхронизация через плагин) и в проекте так же присутствуют .so